# In MySQL, how do I count zero if a LEFT JOIN doesn't match anything?

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

I'm using MySql 5.5.37.  I have a query meant to count the number of times a user logged in

```
select u.id, IFNULL(count(*), 0) 
FROM user u left join logins l 
on u.id = l.user_id group by u.id;
```

The problem is, if a user has never logged in, the above is still returning a count of one for that user, probably because the LEFT JOIN returns a NULL when there isn't a matching row.  How do I change this so that I get zero if the user has never logged in, and then the appropriate count if they have logged in at least once?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use count on one of the columns of right table.

```
select u.id,
    count(l.user_id)
from user u
left join logins l on u.id = l.user_id
group by u.id
```

Comment: I suggest adding `count(IFNULL(l.user_id , 0) )` to avoid null counts, and I recommend to always end the query with semi colon.

Comment: @IlyesTounsi but if you return `0` for `null` rows, doesn't `count(0)` still mean it will increment?

Answer (score 2):

In left joint when the user had never logged in `l.user_id = null` in the result so try this should work :

```
select 
    u.id,
    sum(if(l.user_id is not null,1,0)) 
FROM user u left join logins l on u.id = l.user_id group by u.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

reverse the count

```
select u.id, count(IFNULL(l.user_id , 0) )
FROM user u 
left join logins l on u.id = l.user_id 
group by u.id;
```